# Looping through a Map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `Map` object:

```
let dateJobMap = new Map();

for (let jobInArray of this.state.jobs) {
  let deliveryDate: Date = new Date(jobInArray.DeliveryDate);
  let deliveryDateString: string = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");

  if (dateJobMap.has(deliveryDateString)) {
    let jobsForDate: IDeliveryJob[] = dateJobMap.get(deliveryDateString);
    jobsForDate.push(jobInArray);
  }
  else {
    let jobsForDate: IDeliveryJob[] = [jobInArray];
    dateJobMap.set(deliveryDateString, jobsForDate);
  }
}
```

In my `render` method, I want to call a TruckJobComp object for each delivery job in the value's array to display it:

```
        <div className={ styles.column }>
          <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>

          {
            dateJobMap.forEach(function(jobsForDate, dateString) {
              jobsForDate.map(job => (
                <TruckJobComp job = { job } />
              ))
            })
          }
        </div>
```

This seems like it should work but doesn't.  It never creates a TruckJobComp.  I do a `.forEach` iteration on my `Map`, and for each `value`'s `array`, I use `.map` to get the individual job object to send to TruckJobComp object.

When I create a temp `array` to grab the jobs from the last loop:

```
let tempJobs: IDeliveryJob[];
```

and in the loop add in:

```
  if (dateJobMap.has(deliveryDateString)) {
    let jobsForDate: IDeliveryJob[] = dateJobMap.get(deliveryDateString);
    jobsForDate.push(jobInArray);

    tempJobs = jobsForDate;
  }
```

and then use that `array` in the render:

```
          <div className={ styles.column }>
            <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
            {
              tempJobs.map(job => (
                <TruckJobComp job = { job }/>
              ))
            }
          </div>
```

It displays as expected.

I do have a warnings in Visual Studio Code:

```
Warning - tslint - ...\TruckDeliverySchedule.tsx(104,38): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
```

I don't know enough to understand.  Line 104 corresponds with:

```
dateJobMap.forEach(function(jobsForDate, dateString) {
```

I am very new to this so I'm not 100% sure how most of this works.  Just trying to put pieces I've learned together to get things to work.

Second Edit:

{escape(this.props.description)}

```
{
  [...dateJobMap.keys()].map(jobsForDate => // line 154
    jobsForDate.map(job => (
      <TruckJobComp job = { job } />
    ))
  )
}
```

Produces error:

```
[09:06:56] Error - typescript - src\...\TruckDeliverySchedule.tsx(154,27): error TS2461: Type 'IterableIterator<any>' is not an array type.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`dateJobMap.forEach(...)` returns `undefined`, so it cannot be mapped to a collection of elements.

ES6 maps have `forEach` method for compatibility purposes (generally `for..of` is preferred to iterate over iterables) and don't have `map` method. A map should be converted to array first, then it could be mapped to an element. Since values aren't used, only keys need to be retrieved:

```
  {
    [...dateJobMap.keys()].map(jobsForDate =>
      jobsForDate.map(job => (
        <TruckJobComp job = { job } />
      ))
    )
  }
```

Comment: I am fairly new to typescript/javascript development (I've done 7 years of iOS) and I apologize, I don't completely understand the sample code you provided.  What are the `...`? And why is the `...dateJobMap.keys()` bracketed like that?  And I'm not beholden to use `.forEach`, was just the first one I found.

Comment: As it's mentioned, it converts a map to an array. `dateJobMap.keys()` is `Map` method that returns [an iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), and [... spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) converts an iterable to an array when used with `[]` array literal.s

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Much still to learn. I tried the block of code and I get an error; I updated the question. That's why I asked for clarification, I though it might have been shorthand for something I should already know.

Comment: I didn't notice typescript tag on the question. The problem is specific to TS. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605880/3731501 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964577/3731501 . You should either enable `downlevelIteration` compiler option or replace `[...dateJobMap.keys()]` with `Array.from(dateJobMap.keys())`.

Comment: Yep, that cleared the error.  I had to change it to `.values()` to get the array I needed.  The TruckJobComp is now being rendered!.  I think this is taking me in the right direction, thank you very much!

Comment: Had a similar issue and was able to solve it using this approach but with the use of `.entries()` instead, thanks @EstusFlask !

Comment: @JuaniCondina Set/map iterator iterates over things that make sense in that context, `[...map]` is the same as `[...map.entries()]`, and `[...set]` is the same as `[...set.values()]`.

Answer (score 2):

All this warning is saying is that instead of using the syntax `function(jobsForDate, dateString) {}` you should use the syntax `(jobsForDate, dateString) => {}`.

The reason could be the way `this` is scoped in arrow functions versus function expressions.  See [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

My guess as to the reason your first approach didn't work but your second one did is that `forEach` doesn't actually return an array, and if it did, calling `map` within `forEach` would return an array of arrays (but, again, it doesn't). Not sure how React would handle that, but React does know how to handle a single array, which is what your last approach returns.

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't return an array in of itself, but it should return the `Map`'s `value` which is an array.  I've confirmed this outside of the render method by console.loging it.

Comment: If you check out the documentation of the `.forEach` method you will see that it returns `undefined`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: You can see this confirmed in this trivial example that I ran in the REPL. Notice when you check the value of `a` you get the Map, but when you check `b` you get nothing, i.e. undefined.  https://imgur.com/SjDtUIc

Comment: Jared, your example is true.  When I do the `.forEach' loop fore the render and console.log the variables, they have values.  JobsForDate logs as a array.  I'll update the question.

Comment: After more thought and playing with, I understand what you were saying.  While the array I need is avaible in the loop scope, the `.forEach` doesn't return anything to the `<div>` to display.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a Map, we can use for..of and forEach() loop constructs.
Map provides three methods that return iterable: map.keys(), map.values() and map.entries().

Iteration over Maps is always in insertion order.

```
                    let map = new Map()
                    
                    map.set("one", "first element");
                    map.set("two", "second element");
                    map.set(3, "third element");    
                    
                         for (let [key, value] of map) {
                                console.log(key+" : "+value);
                                }
                
                map.keys() - Returns an iterable for keys
                map.values() - Returns an iterable for values
                map.entries() - Returns an iterable of key,value
            
            Example
            
            for (let key of map.keys()) {
                console.log(key);
            }
            
            // output
            // one
            // two
            // 3
            
            for (let value of map.values()){
                console.log(value);
            }
            
            // output
            // first element
            // second element
            // third element
            
            for (let [key, value] of  map.entries()) {
                console.log(key + " = " + value)
            }
            
            //output
            // one = first element
            // two = second element
            // 3 = third element
        
        map.forEach(function(value, key) {
            console.log(key + " = " + value);
        })
        
        //output
        // one = first element
        // two = second element
        // 3 = third element
```

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for the entire answer, you seem to have done that for all your recent answers. If you are struggling with the formatting tools, remember that indenting text is a shortcut to formatting it as code, and have a look at the "preview" section below the editor to make sure it's looking the way you intended.

Comment: Changes done as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate the value set using Typescript, rather than iterating the key set use this method. But don't forget to update the target es version in the tsconfig.json file under compilerOptions

```
[...p.delData_c.entries()].map(([key, value]) =>
     <PickedIItemPack group={value} />
)
```

in tsconfig.json add this line

```
"target": "es2015"
```

under compilerOptions scope