# Array object received from service but cannot iterate through it?

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, iteration

I have got a recipe web app, and i have a 'add recipe' page with a child component 'add ingredient' nested and called within its HTML as seen here:

```
<h2>Add {{addRecipeForm.controls.name.value}}</h2>
<form [formGroup]="addRecipeForm">
  ...
  <app-add-ingredient></app-add-ingredient>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit">Add new recipe</button> <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button> <button (click)="test()">check if array was caught</button>
</form>
<p>Recipe ingredient list (from service)</p>
<div *ngIf="ingredientList">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Units and Style</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let ingre of ingredientList">
    <td>{{ingre.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{ingre.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ingre.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{ingre.unitsAndStyle}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I then added a button to ensure the data sent from the service was actually received in correct format etc (as seen in the screenshot I got it sends the object perfectly when the child component adds the ingredient) but when I try and present it with the table as shown I get this error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'fawf'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

[image]

I know the service isnt the problem because my 'test()' function just logs the array and its all there as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Is there supposed to be some array showing in the console window screenshot? I see an object where name = 'fawf', and ID = 20, but no array. An array would display in square brackets, not curly ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround found here [Iterate over object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular#answer-34074484)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'values',  pure: false })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }
}
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392
This seems to list a similar issue and they resolved it by making a small 'hack' to overcome that error.

```
hack(val) {
  return Array.from(val);
}
```