# How to iterate through this json response in angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am getting the following response from a service, which includes form definition in json schema format.

[image: Json response]

Now I want to iterate this response in angular component.

So I have fetched all the schema elements like this in one Formdata variable.

```
          res['tabs'].forEach(element => {
              this.tablist.push(element);

            });


       this.tablist.forEach(element => {

            this.FormData[element] = res['com'][element]['schema'];
            this.FormValueData[element] = res['com'][element]['data'];
            this.FetchValueParam[element] = res['com'][element]['data'];
        });
```

Now I want to access the value of Formdata in side a view and I have wrote following code for it.

```
                  <form>
                      <div *ngFor='let input1 of FormData[element]['properties']'>

                        <label [for]='input1.type'> input1.title</label>
                        <input type='input1.type' [name]='input1.title' 
                       [placeholder]='something'>
                        <br>
                      </div>
                      <br><br>
                      <button type="submit"> Submit </button>



                   </form>
```

But I am not able to access this it as an array as it is a json object. I have tried Array.of() and Array.from() but it is not working with the following error. How to iterate through the json and create form fields?

```
            Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

**Update:** When I am using a dummy json object like this. I am getting desired result. So what I am getting is , there is some serious mismatch between type expected by ngFor and type I am supplying as a json object.

```
               this.inputfield=
             [{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:"your email here"},
            {type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your email 
               here'},{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your 
                 email here'},
            {type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your email 
                here'},{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your 
              email here'},
             {type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your email 
               here'},{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your 
             email here'},
             {type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your email 
             here'},{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your 
             email 
             here'}{type:'email',name:'email',value:'',placeholder:'your 
              email here'}];
```

When I checked the difference between both of them in json schema validator,
The Former I showed in console is coming as object but the above is coming is array.

So Either I send array not object or I create one array or class based on above json schema at run time. What is better to do?

Comment: That JSON response is not an array, it is a huge OBJECT, you are trying to iterate through "properties" object. You cant do that

Comment: Ok so how to convert it to array? is there any way to do it directly???

Comment: Can I convert the property object to array while I am fetching it on server side?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to array? As i can see from that picuture (its not good idea to post a picture) there is no repetition, and you dont need to loop through it, You can access it like this: `FormData[element]['properties'].accountcatalogid.title, FormData[element]['properties'].bankaccountname.title` etc.

Comment: If properties is map they you need to find way to iterate through map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular

Comment: I need to convert it to array so that I can create dynamic form based on the fields in properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that **this.tablist** is an array of strings you can change the object being created in this.FormData[element] to an array:

```
    this.tablist.forEach(element => {
        Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).forEach(inputKey => {
            this.FormData[element] = [];
            this.FormData[element].push(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][inputKey]);
        }
        this.FormValueData[element] = res['com'][element]['data'];
        this.FetchValueParam[element] = res['com'][element]['data'];
    });
```

And then use it in the template as shown below.

`<div *ngFor='let input1 of FormData[element]'>`

Also, you are not using property binding right on this line(that is if you don't have a variable named something in the component):

`[placeholder]='something'>`.

It should be

`[placeholder]='"something"'>`

Comment: when I apply above changes. console says "_this.FormData[element].properties.push is not a function"

Comment: you can declare it below the forEach function: `this.FormData[element]['properties'] = []`

Comment: When I tried this this.FormData[element]['properties']  = [];  it says can not set 'properties' on undefined.  When I remove the [element] and just accessed the data in this.FormData['properties'] it worked. but I need to have identified for [element] . what I am missing?

Comment: I am really one step away from what I am trying to achieve. I really don't know why when I did as per your suggestion this.FormData[element]['properties'] = []; it is showing the error that "can not set 'properties' on undefined" element here is defined and I am able to get it in console.

Comment: I'm glad, can you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: This has solved many of my probs. I need not to convert the json object  in type script class. This array will do my work.

Comment: One more thing I am stuck with this is, How to use this form elements in two way data binding? I need to create either template driven or reactive form , I am confused between both of them that which one is good to use in this situation?

Comment: I think in your case you can use template driven forms and using [(ngModel)] you can obtain the two-way data binding

Comment: Hi Victor, Thanks for your suggestion. I was not able to create such large number of variables in .ts files So  I have used the below syntax and got the values of all fields in custom_submit function : <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="custom_submit(f.value)">  . So My question is if I do the same thing for on change event of form ? can I still have all flexibility to apply conditional validations and on field change events without binding a single input. Because the array I am getting has all the values and input keys.