# What is the correct way of using *ngFor with an iterator?

Tags: angular, iterator

TL;DR:
Angular raises `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when using an iterator with `ngFor`.

---

I have a template which uses `ngFor` like:

```
<div *ngFor="let something of foobarIterator()">
```

The TypeScript code being like:

```
private foobar = [];

public foobarIterator() {
    return this.foobar[Symbol.iterator]();
}
```

According to Angular documentation it is allowed to pass an iterator to [*ngForOf*](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForOf) and it actually works… except it throws an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` afterwards.

While I understand that it may be because I return a new instance of iterator every time the method is called, I do not get what Angular expects instead. Using the same instance of the iterator after it has been exhausted makes no sense – it's an iterator after all, not the array itself.

What is the correct way of using iterators with `ngFor` then?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537666/3079262) and [solutions proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536052/3079262) several times .. although not too easy to find.

[Angular 6.1.0](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v6-1-now-available-typescript-2-9-scroll-positioning-and-more-9f1c03007bb6) finally provides a new pipe `keyvalue` ([API docs](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)) which can be used on Objects and Maps like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'keyvalue-pipe',
  template: `<span>
    <p>Object</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
    <p>Map</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
  </span>`
})
export class KeyValuePipeComponent {
  object: {[key: number]: string} = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
  map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
}
```

Comment: It is answer fot another question!
Original qustion still big issue.