# Display Enum key as string in TypeScript / Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

```
export enum Type {
    TYPE_1 : "Apple",
    TYPE_2 : "Orange",
    TYPE_3 : "Banana"
}
```

When I log `Type.TYPE_1`, `toString` method is called by default.

```
console.log(Type.TYPE_1 + " is " + Type.TYPE_1.toString());

Output => Apple is Apple
```

My expectation is result is like

```
Output : TYPE_1 is Apple
```

How can I log/get the key `TYPE_1` as string?

*Is there way to do `override method` like as below?*

```
export enum Type {
    TYPE_1 : "Apple",
    TYPE_2 : "Orange",
    TYPE_3 : "Banana"

    toString() {
        this.key + " is " + this.toString();
        <or>
        this.key + " is " + this.value();
    }
}
```

I already googling for that, I am not OK yet.

**Update**

The purpose is to show in UI

```
export enum Currency {
    USD : "US Dollar",
    MYR : "Malaysian Ringgit",
    SGD : "Singapore Dollar",
    INR : "Indian Rupee",
    JPY : "Japanese Yen"
}

currencyList : Currency[]= [Currency.USD, Currency.MYR, Currency.SGD, Currency.INR, Currency.JPY];

<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let currency of currencyList">
        <td>
            <input name="radioGroup" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" [value]="currency">

            <label>{{currency}} is {{currency.toString()}}</label>    
            <!--
                here expectiation is Example 
                    USD is US Dollar
                    MYR is Malaysian Ringgit
                    SGD is Singapore Dollar
                    ....

                Now I get "US Dollar is US Dollar"....
            -->             
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That `enum` syntax is wrong, please check this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Is the solution provided by me worked for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713969/8593983

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe like below, working example is here in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-if1xbv) and your `enum` syntax is wrong... please check [Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

**Note:** Below one is for **Angular 6**

Please check [Angular 6.1 introduces a new KeyValue Pipe](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/angular-6-1-introduces-new-keyvalue-pipe/)

**types.ts code**

```
export enum Type {
  USD = "US Dollar",
  MYR = "Malaysian Ringgit",
  SGD = "Singapore Dollar",
  INR = "Indian Rupee",
  JPY = "Japanese Yen"
}
```

**Component.ts code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Type } from './types';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  states = Type;
}
```

**Component.template code**

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let state of states | keyvalue">
        <td>
            <input name="radioGroup" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" [value]="currency">
            <label>{{state.key + " is " + state.value}}</label>             
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

For **Angular < 6** please check one of the stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular)

Answer (score 3):

I just have a function in my .ts file

```
StoreListingTypeString(type: StoreListingType): string {
  return StoreListingType[type];
}
```

Then call that function in my html

```
{{StoreListingTypeString(listing.listingType)}}
```

Comment: by far the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, enum syntax will be

```
enum Type {
    TYPE_1 = "Apple",
    TYPE_2 = "Orange",
    TYPE_3 = "Banana"
}
```

By default, you can not do this straightforwardly. You can't get the keys of your enum. 
But, you can achieve it by iteration, which will not be the best thing you know.
You can try

```
console.log(Object.keys(Type).find(key => Type[key] === Type.TYPE_1)+ " is "+ Type.TYPE_1);
```

**Update:**

As you construct the array manually

```
currencyList : Currency[]= [Currency.USD, Currency.MYR, Currency.SGD, Currency.INR, Currency.JPY];
```

then,  why not add a map here and then iterate through it

```
let curList = new Map()
    .set("USD","US Dollar")
    .set("MYR","Malaysian Dollar")
    .set("SGD", "Singapore Dollar");
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Few clarifications before we get to the answer,

- As others already mentioned, the string enum syntax should be -

```
export enum Currency {
  USD = "US Dollar",
  MYR = "Malaysian Ringgit",
  SGD = "Singapore Dollar",
  INR = "Indian Rupee",
  JPY = "Japanese Yen"
}
```

- I don't think here the `toString` method understanding is right. Consider it more like an JS object:
  `const currency = { "USD" : "US Dollar", "MYR" : "Malaysian Ringgit" }`
  When you're passing a key to a object, its always gonna return the value, irrespective of whether you use `toString` or not.

Now coming to the solution , I have never worked in Angular, so advance apologies for Angular syntax.
But I faced a similar issue where I needed to show the key strings in a dropdown.I made it work by looping through the enum as an object. For this specific problem, instead of,

```
const currencyList : Currency[]= [Currency.USD, Currency.MYR, Currency.SGD, Currency.INR, Currency.JPY];
```

I might have done :

```
const currencyCodes = Object.keys(Currency) 
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let currencyCode of currencyCodes">
        <td>
            <input name="radioGroup" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" [value]="currency">
            <label>{{currencyCode}} is {{Currency[currencyCode]}}</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```