# Angular *ngFor not returning list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data which I need to add to a select.

Here is the data:

```js
data = [{
  name: 'test',
  list: {
    0: 'zero',
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two'
  }
}];
```

```html
<select name="myselect">
  <option *ngFor="let ls of data" [value]="ls">{{ ls.list }} {{i}}</option>
</select>
```

The Result is:  `[object Object] 0`

I need to display:

```
zero
one
two
```

and the **values as 0, 1, 2** etc

How can I do this with this data?

Comment: You need to add json pipe to display object

<option *ngFor="let ls of data" [value]="ls">{{ ls.list | json }} {{i}}</option>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use keyvalue pipe because is an opject not an array

```
<select
  name="myselect"
>
<option *ngFor="let ls of data[0].list | keyvalue;let i = index" [value]="ls.key">
{{ ls.value}} {{i}}</option>
</select>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gprkuf)

Answer (score 1):

Improved the answer of @malbarmawi, so arrays > 1 can be used

```
<select name="myselect">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ls of data">
    <option *ngFor="let item of (ls.list | keyvalue)" [value]="item.key">
      {{ item.value }} {{ i }}
    </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr2mer

Comment: that can be good ,  but in that case simplify the data structure to just an array will be better