# Iterating over an object from the database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

i'm doing project with angular and firebase. I get an object from firebase and I would like to display it in html, but I don't know how to get value from the object in the array.
How can I iterate through auto indexes from the firebase ?

This is calls Firebase:

```
getListTasks() {
  return this.db.list('/Tasks').valueChanges();
}
```

This is my component:

```
this.taskService.getListTasks().subscribe(t => {
      this.todoTasks = t;
    });
```

This is my object in the array : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/npowv.jpg

Comment: Hi @student_it -- could you post your Angular code and the code that calls Firebase.

Comment: Of course, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the object into an array for you to iterate over like below

```
  this.taskService.getListTasks().subscribe(tasks => {

  const tasksArray = Object.keys(tasks).map((key, index) => {
      const task = tasks[key];
      return task;
    });
    this.todoTasks = tasksArray;
  });
```

Angular also has a built in mechanism for doing this using the key-value pipe

I highly recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261193/5927361)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the todoTasks is an array, this is how you would implement.

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todoTasks">
  <div *ngFor="let value of todo.myMap.values()">
    {{value.attribute}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it.doesn't work because in array is object and in object are objects.

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: You mean you have a map of objects in your object?

Comment: Yes, I have a map of objects in your object.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a look at it. Here is a tutorial for your problem I think: https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/for-of-loop/