# Using _.groupby() lodash with *ngFor - object error

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I'm using lodash to group by array:

```
venuesByCategory: {};

// ...

this.venuesByCategory = _.groupBy(allVenues, venue => venue.category);
```

In my template:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let venue of venuesByCategory | keyvalue">
<!-- -->
</ion-row>
```

i got error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

what should i do? console.log of venuesByCategory:
[image]

Comment: Hello, When are you doing the following code ?
this.venuesByCategory = _.groupBy(allVenues, venue => venue.category);

Comment: Just curious, does adding braces around the pipe do any good? => `*ngFor="let venue of (venuesByCategory | keyvalue)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error explains it all.

You are trying to iterate object using `*ngFor` which is not supported.

Lodash `groupBy` returns object and not array.

Please follow below answer if you want to display object keys.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537666/3569893