# ngFor angular loop in an object of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, object

```
object = [{id='1',name="cosette"},{id='2',name="koko"},{id='3',name="krysto"}]
```

i want to display the object in row and columns dynamically

want i want to get 
i tried to do

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let data of object">
<ion-col > {{data.id}}</ion-col>
<ion-col> {{data.name}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

i don't want to use name and id i need to let it be dynamic. 
any help ?

Comment: Use `{{ data.id }}` and `{{ data.name }}`.

Comment: i want to get the answer dynamicaly without using id and name

Comment: That isn't dynamic?

Comment: for exemple: if i have  object =[{id='1', name='cosette',work:'teacher'}] i want to write the same code for both exemple and get all the attributes in the columns

Comment: Iterate over objects with an Angular pipe... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular 6.1 you can use a [KeyValue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let o of object">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let data of o | keyvalue"> {{data.value}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[image]
StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kyasru).

Answer (score -2):

Your Json is not a in good format it should be

```
object = [{'id':'1','name':"cosette"},{'id':'2',name:"koko"},{'id':'3','name':"krysto"}];
```

Please take at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-snk7wp?file=app%2Fapp.html)

Comment: OP says they don't want to use explicitly use properties `id` and `name. Your stackblitz explicitly uses those properties. Therefore, really not an answer.

Comment: OP says also "i need to let it be dynamic", it means that he doesn't want to use static values in html, i think you did not get the question, let's see if OP finds my answer helpful or not