# Json data showing up on webpage but not falling into table columns

Tags: angular

How would I go about getting each vehicle attribute to fall into their respective columns?

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles ">
        <td><pre>{{vehicle | json }}</pre></td>
        <td>{{vehicle.DecodedVehicleLeafId | json}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.Description | json}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.IsSummarizedData | json}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.IsActive | json}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.SourceBrandCode | json}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.Attribute1 | json}}</td>  
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/vehicles','edit', vehicle.VehicleCatalogId]">View</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
export interface Vehicle { 
    VehicleCatalogId?: string;
    DecodedVehicleLeafId?: string;
    Description?: string;
    IsSummarizedData?: boolean;
    IsActive?: boolean;
    SourceBrandCode?: string;
    VehicleYear?: string;
    Attribute1?: string;
}
```

```js
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.vehiclesService.getAllVehicles()
    .subscribe({
      next: (vehicles) => {
        console.log(vehicles)
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
}
```

```js
getAllVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]>{return this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/ingress');}
```

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxP6c.png)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with angular, but setting up tables is not too different from react or other javascript/html frameworks. Since your image shows the headers are set up fine, my guess is that it has to do with how you're mapping the rows. I found this post that seems to address your issue, needing to use a pipe to assist angular with the map, in the <tr>: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular/31537666#31537666 . Hope that helps

Comment: I updated my answer in hopes that it might help you find the problem. However, if it does not, please try to recreate the issue in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and I will gladly help you find out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Json pipe

You shouldn't have to pipe everything with the json pipe. That was just to help you see what is in the object.

#### Example

Here's a very basic example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m3uf4f?file=src/app/app.component.html). So, I don't see anything wrong with your initial approach to populating the table.

#### Possible Problem

You need to make sure the keys in your `Vehicle` interface map perfectly to those of the objects returned by your endpoint. They are case-sensitive, so are you sure they start with capital letters?

*I notice you defined all the interface members as optional with `?` (= elvis). If they aren't optional (like I would assume things like id aren't) they shouldn't be marked as such.*