# Can't read object of object Json file | angular | typescript | ngfor

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object

Helloo !

i would use a json files in my angular-app.

I have a local json file 'client.json'

```
{
  "T001": {
    "name": "admin",
    "type": "adm",
    "id": "1",
    "class": "viewer",
  },
  "T002": {
    "name": "Customer",
    "type": "usr",
    "id": "2",
    "class": "viewer",
  },
  "T003": {
    "name": "DB450",
    "type": "air",
    "id": "3",
    "class": "gateway",
  },
  "T004": {
    "name": "DB620",
    "type": "air",
    "id": "4",
    "class": "gateway",
  }
}
```

Actually, i could read this file and i got access to the name of object (object of object) -- T003.name for example and using console.log to display the result but this is not what i'm looking for because i can't use this variable into html template.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as tunnelsData from '../data/client.json'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 objects: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.objects = (tunnelsData as any).default;
    console.log(this.object);

  }
}
```

I'm looking for loads this file into a variable, then using this variable on a html template with ngfor like this :

```
<my-app *ngFor="let T of objects"
               [tunnel]="T"
               [name]="T.name"><my-app>
```

tunnel and name are two variables of my second component
To display at the end an example like this :

Tunnel : T001 (which the first object of my file)

Name : admin  (which an object of the first object)
.
.
.

I hope it's clear for you.

any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your error? I see, that  this.objects = (tunnelsData as any).default is using .default but what is .default? I cant find it in your json file.

Comment: Your JSON file contains an object and not an array. So you need to create an array from it.

Comment: @Schrader, thanks for your response, i use the .default to display the json file by default, 
error message :  Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

Comment: @corol in your `json` you don't have an `array`. You have an `object` having different keys. So first you have to create an object if you want to loop in your html

Comment: @riorudo thank you, 
can you explain more ? i'm learning this langage

Comment: Have a look at the answer of @Fahad Subzwari. He creates a list with all object keys "T001", "T002"... and in the html file he loops over the key list with `*ngFor` and accesses the individual object data by key. That's a nice way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that you don't have an `array` in your `json` data. you have this data as an `object`

```
{
 "T001": {
  "name": "admin",
  "type": "adm",
  "id": "1",
  "class": "viewer",
},
 "T002": {
 "name": "Customer",
 "type": "usr",
 "id": "2",
 "class": "viewer",
},
 "T003": {
 "name": "DB450",
 "type": "air",
 "id": "3",
 "class": "gateway",
},
 "T004": {
 "name": "DB620",
 "type": "air",
 "id": "4",
 "class": "gateway",
 }
}
```

And in your `html` you are trying to loop through your elements with `ngFor`. So `ngFor` directive always expects an `array` to loop in `html`.

So the simple solution you can have is that in your component you can do like this

`app.component.ts`

```
this.objects = (tunnelsData as any).default;
this.objectKeys = Object.keys(his.objects); // ['T001', 'T002', 'T003', 'T004']
```

And inside of your `html` you can do like this

```
<my-app *ngFor="let keyName of objectKeys" [tunnel]="objects[keyName]" [name]="objects[keyName]?.name"><my-app>
```

What i am doing here is that first i am getting all of the keys of your `object` as an `array` and then i am iterating over the array of `keys`. And in `html` i am accessing the individual `object` by it's key name which is coming from `ngFor` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Generaly, angular does not support iterating over objects in ngFor.
Check your browser's dev tools console. There should be an error.
You can use pipe in ngFor to make it work [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).
For more details check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular).
And to display the key (eg."T001"), you would need to pass it too.

```
    *ngFor="let item of objects | keyvalue"
               [tunnel]="item.value"
               [name]="item.value.name"
               [key]="item.key"
```

Comment: Good luck learning angular 